# SQL querying a max value based off other columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm wanting the max rank within each reservation as well as franchise over time. Any thoughts on how to query this?

```
id  reservation date    franch  rank
1   1           6/1/2017    1   234
2   1           6/1/2017    1   465
3   1           6/1/2017    1   851
4   1           6/1/2017    1   956
1   1           6/2/2017    2   658
2   1           6/2/2017    2   578
3   1           6/2/2017    2   578
4   1           6/2/2017    2   954
5   2           6/1/2017    1   436
6   2           6/1/2017    1   645
7   2           6/1/2017    1   854
8   2           6/1/2017    1   145
5   2           6/2/2017    3   98
6   2           6/2/2017    3   345
7   2           6/2/2017    3   867
8   2           6/2/2017    3   909
```

The output should like like... but note I'm also hoping to not return multiple records such as the 578 for reservation 1 on 6/2/17 and franchise 2.

```
id  reservation date    franch  rank
4   1           6/1/2017    1   956
2   1           6/2/2017    2   578
3   1           6/2/2017    2   578
7   2           6/1/2017    1   854
8   2           6/2/2017    3   909
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`QUALIFY`](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.083.016.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY reservation,date,franch ORDER BY rank DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, I would probably go for:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.reservation = t.reservation and t2.date = t.date 
              order by t2.rank desc
              fetch first 1 row only
             );
```

But I don't think Teradata supports such constructs.  If I assume you want the highest id, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.reservation = t.reservation and t2.date = t.date 
             );
```

Or you can use `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by reservation, date order by rank desc) = 1;
```

The use of `row_number()` ensures one row per `reservation`/`date`, so you don't get duplicates.

Comment: I think the third example got it! Could you explain to me (or direct me somewhere) how qualify, over, and partition by work in this query?

Comment: Here's a link to the [documentation from Teradata](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1145-160K%2Ftrx1472241101957.html%23wwID0EPDAE) on window functions.  I think that will answer the bulk of your questions.

Comment: @JustinB . . . `qualify` is `where` for window functions.